# Oracle view columns empty

Tags: excel, oracle, powerpivot

We use commodity trading software linked to an Oracle database to export reports to Excel. I'm connecting to this Oracle database using PowerPivot as well as SQL developer. In doing so, I'm able to connect to Oracle directly creating live, refreshable reports which no longer need to be constantly exported.

I located an Oracle view responsible for generating one of the most important reports we export to Excel. What's strange is that all of the columns are completely empty. When I open it using PowerPivot or SQL Developer, I just see the headers which contain no data. It populates with data just fine when exported from our trading software however.

Does anyone know why this might be and how I can get this view to populate the data (using PowerPivot for example)?

Is this a materialized view I'm dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be it has to do with permissions or row-level security on the view. Whether it is materialized view is impossible to determine from the data you've provided, but should make no difference in accessing the data from Power Pivot.

This is a question for your DBAs and unlikely a problem in Power Pivot.